# Flutter Android TV: app crashes when loading streams quickly one after another

Tags: android, flutter, android-tv, skia, smart-tv

I created a test app for Flutter on Android TV that can play external streams via a streamingUrl. Initially loading the stream and playing it works fine.

The problem starts when I want to 'zap' through the different streams that are available by using the channel up/down buttons on the remote control.
When doing this often, at a certain point the app will crash giving me nothing more than a 'tombstone' with a vague description of what went wrong.

I already tried the Flutter profiler to check if it is memory/performance related, but so far that does not seem to be the problem.

Also: there are devices with varying hardware specs on which this problem never occurs.

I'm using the Android Media3 library with some customizations to play the stream and handle DRM cases. So the playing of the stream is handled natively.

It seems that the Skia rendering engine wants to render a frame, but fails to do so, causing a crash at some point. But why and how this is happening is still a big mystery to me.

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction to solve this issue, by answering one of the following questions:

- Is this a known issue?
- Could it be caused by the Flutter rendering engine?
- Will Impeller maybe solve this issue, and should I just wait until that is released?
- Other pointers would be great as well!

The tombstone's stacktrace starts with this line:

```
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe675b014
```

The last method that was called and is readable looks like this:

```
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #05 pc 00646385  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (eglCreateImageKHR+948) (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
```

The entire tombstone starting from the SIGSEGV looks like this:

```
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe675b014
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A      r0  e675b000  r1  e675b001  r2  00000001  r3  00000001
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A      r4  b7017600  r5  bcc47888  r6  00000001  r7  ccc555b0
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A      r8  e7d48260  r9  bcc47984  r10 9bbc3968  r11 b7017600
2024-01-24 14:49:16.152 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A      ip  bcc47838  sp  bcc47870  lr  e7cfc98b  pc  ccfcfd86
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #00 pc 0063dd86  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #01 pc 0063e39f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #02 pc 00640243  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #03 pc 0063ff09  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #04 pc 0063f95f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #05 pc 00646385  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (eglCreateImageKHR+948) (BuildId: dfee92a81a346322de88278804aa7d5a)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #06 pc 00016e87  /system/lib/libEGL.so (void* android::eglCreateImageTmpl<int, void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned int, void*, int const*)>(void*, void*, unsigned int, void*, int const*, void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned int, void*, int const*))+310) (BuildId: 9c077f0f22a38f0ef41b19770721e8ec)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #07 pc 00016d43  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::eglCreateImageKHRImpl(void*, void*, unsigned int, void*, int const*)+22) (BuildId: 9c077f0f22a38f0ef41b19770721e8ec)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #08 pc 002315f9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrAHardwareBufferUtils::MakeBackendTexture(GrContext*, AHardwareBuffer*, int, int, void (**)(void*), void**, bool, GrBackendFormat const&, bool)+136) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #09 pc 00231293  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN31GrAHardwareBufferImageGenerator9makeProxyEP18GrRecordingContextE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS5_EEF5sk_spI9GrSurfaceEP18GrResourceProviderEEclEOSC_$2219a8229c88f20838122b4c217f5d45+70) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #10 pc 001e4b9b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrSurfaceProxyPriv::doLazyInstantiation(GrResourceProvider*)+70) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #11 pc 00196163  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrResourceAllocator::addInterval(GrSurfaceProxy*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+322) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #12 pc 003dec5f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_19TextureOp12visitProxiesERKNSt3__18functionIFvP14GrSurfaceProxyEEEN4GrOp11VisitorTypeE$ab67424b01b2ae857b75443a16f18610+90) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #13 pc 0019385d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrRenderTargetOpList::OpChain::visitProxies(std::__1::function<void (GrSurfaceProxy*)> const&, GrOp::VisitorType) const+40) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #14 pc 001937a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrRenderTargetOpList::gatherProxyIntervals(GrResourceAllocator*) const+116) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.297 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #15 pc 001fc6ff  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrDrawingManager::flush(GrSurfaceProxy*, SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+638) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #16 pc 001fc3f3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrDrawingManager::prepareSurfaceForExternalIO(GrSurfaceProxy*, SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+118) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #17 pc 001fc2c9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (GrRenderTargetContext::prepareForExternalIO(SkSurface::BackendSurfaceAccess, GrFlushFlags, int, GrBackendSemaphore*, void (*)(void*), void*)+92) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #18 pc 001fc265  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::flush()+22) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #19 pc 001b8f87  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>, SkMatrix const&)+146) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #20 pc 001b8ca1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+272) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #21 pc 001fa2d5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+216) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #22 pc 001f98b1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+176) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #23 pc 002050c3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+158) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #24 pc 00204f1b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+54) (BuildId: ab1701da2387beb5140b7e133cfadf83)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #25 pc 0000d903  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+182) (BuildId: 5033a2d0383ba79896a60621c50f40e1)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #26 pc 000a6087  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: f2641c48dc0dc78cb6357b8c19e46a43)
2024-01-24 14:49:16.299 29103-29103 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #27 pc 00060141  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: f2641c48dc0dc78cb6357b8c19e46a43)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and the problem was that I was not releasing the player (calling player.release()) after each zap.

You say it's not a memory problem but may be give it a try.